# Проблема с функцией

Tags: c, функции

Требуется сделать программу для сравнения (на больше-меньше) двух введённых строк. Сравнение должно выполняться в отдельной функции. Причем в функции не должно содержаться конструкций ввода-вывода. Как сделать так, чтобы вывод результата в происходил в функции **main**, а не **compare**:

```
void compare(char *str, char *str1)
{
int i, k;

//Считаем количество символов
for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++);
for(k = 0; str1[k] != '\0'; k++);

//Сравниваем и выводим результат
if(i == k) printf("Одинаковые\n");
else
    {
        if(i > k) printf("1-ая больше\n");
        else printf("2-ая больше\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
setlocale (LC_CTYPE,"rus"); // подключение русского языка
char str[82], str1[82];

//Вводим строки
printf("Введите str  не больше 80 символов: ");
gets(str);
printf("Введите str1 не больше 80 символов: ");
gets(str1);

//Обращаемся к функции
compare(str, str1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну сделаю функцию compare чтобы возращала к примеру инт: 0 если равны, 1 если больше 1, 2 если больше 2 строка. Потом через switch проверь в main что вернула функция...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как всегда выкладываю оригинальное решение:

```
const char* compare(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    const char* const strResults[3]={"Вторая длиннее", "Одинаковые по длине", "Первая длиннее"};
    int result=strlen(str1)-strlen(str2);
    return strResults[(result>=0)+(result>0)];
}

int main()
{
    ...
    printf(compare(str1, str2));
}
```

Ещё вариант реализации compare придумал(на основе другого ответа):

```
int compare(const unsigned char* s1, const unsigned char* s2)
{
   while(*s1 && *s2) s1++, s2++;
   return !!*s1+!*s2;
}
```

Comment: Настоящий оригинал! Заменить функцию сравнения строк функцией сравнения длины строк... Да ещё в оригинальном исполнении...

Comment: >Заменить функцию сравнения строк функцией сравнения длины строк...

 Так ему это и надо было судя по его посту.

Comment: Увы. В текст не вглядывался.

Answer (score 1):

Ну более типично возвращать значения (-1, 0, 1).

```
int compare(char *str1, char *str2) {
    while(*str1 && *str2 && *str1 == *str2) str1++, str2++;
    if(*str1 == *str2) return 0;
    return (*str1 < *str2) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто покороче (как просили в вопросе сравниваем именно длины строк)

```
int
compare (unsigned char *s1, unsigned char *s2)
{
  while (*s1 && *s2) {
    s1++; s2++;
  }
  return *s1-*s2;
}
```

Возвращает 0 если длины строк равны, < 0 - первая короче, > 0 вторая короче.

Comment: Придётся приводить строки к unsigned char*. Лучше сделать просто `return strlen(str1)-strlen(str2)` и получить разницу длин строк. А эта функция будет возвращать непонятно что - код последнего символа меньшей строки с плюсом или минусом.

Comment: Если с плюсом -- первая длиннее. С минусом -- вторая.

Comment: Компилятор (gcc) сам нормально приводит char \* к unsigned char \*. По крайней мере у меня никакх warnings не было.

@GLmonster, в последней строке ответа написано какой результат когда возвращается. А два strlen() - это лишняя работа. Представьте ситуацию, когда одна строка пустая, а другая много мегабайт.

Comment: >в последней строке ответа написано какой результат когда возвращается.
Если с плюсом -- первая длиннее. С минусом -- вторая.

 Это я знаю. Я имею в виду, что возращаемое значение кроме как длиннее или короче никакой полезной информации не несёт. А вариант с вычитанием длин строк показывает, насколько именно одна строка длиннее другой.

Comment: Так задача не ставилась. Вообще она в такой формулировке, какая-то за уши притянутая.

Comment: >А два strlen() - это лишняя работа. Представьте ситуацию, когда одна строка пустая, а другая много мегабайт.

 Компилятор, по крайней мере, MSVC подставляет длину строки вместо strlen, если она заранее известна. Так и бывает в большинстве случаев.

 Строки в мегабайт обычно вычисляются или считываются из файла. Их длину обычно можно узнать другим способом. Например, используя std::string, который знает свою длину.

 И не могу себе представить ситуацию, в которой строчка порядка несколько байт сравнивается со строкой в мегабайты.

Comment: По поводу "*кто что знает*" посмотрите ответ [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/77275/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)